# to display items in a listview based on a parameter

Tags: android, listview, parameters

i am displaying only three details from my database in 1 row of the listview after the user clicks on this list item all the details should be made visible in another activity in a list view.i tried but m getting a blank activity to open instead of a list..
**ListViewDetails.java**

```
    listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View view, 
                int position, long id) {
                // Get the cursor, positioned to the corresponding row in the result set
                Cursor cursor = (Cursor) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);

                // Get the state's capital from this row in the database.
                int appno=cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("appln_no"));


                Intent objintent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),DisplayDetails.class);
                objintent.putExtra("countryCode", countryCode);
                startActivity(objintent);

                }
    });
```

here m passing an appno parameter to the next intent so that details related to this appno are displayed in **DisplayDetails.java**

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listdisplay);
        Intent intentobj=getIntent();
        int appno=intentobj.getIntExtra("appln_no", 0);

        WayDataBase way=new WayDataBase(getApplicationContext());

        ArrayList<String> listvalues=way.getListDetails(appno);

        if(listvalues.size()!=0)
        {
            ListView lv=getListView();
            ListAdapter adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(DisplayDetails.this, R.layout.view_animal_entry, R.id.animalName, listvalues);
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        }
 }
```

but the screen is just balnk..
whats the issue??? please help! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Shiv,

You have fetched the values in variable "appno" but set values from variable "countryCode" instead of "appno".

In your DisplayDetails.java, you are trying to fetch it from the the variable "appln_no" which is incorrect.

If i look at your code then it seems that you want to pass appno value to another activity 
so should keep it like this:

**ListViewDetails.java**
objintent.putExtra("countryCode", appno);

**DisplayDetails.java**

int appno=intentobj.getIntExtra("appln_no", "countryCode");